# How to get PostgresHook Airflow Dict Cursor

Tags: python, airflow

Postgreshook in airflow has a function **get_record** that returns the result of a query.
The result is a tuple object. How can we receive the result in a dict form?
Also since the code mentions [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook/index.html) that we can use a dict cursor how do we do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directions given in your link are technically accurate, but unfortunately not very clear as to what "connection" you should be working with.

Modify the relevant Connection in the Airflow web interface's Connections manager so that its `Extra` field contains the following JSON: `{"cursor": "dictcursor"}`.